# Creating SSH tunnel without running the ssh command

Tags: ssh, openssh

Establishing SSH tunnel can done from the command line by explicitly giving

```
ssh -N -f -L 18888:192.168.224.143:8888 username@192.168.224.143
```

or defining tunnel in `~/.ssh/config` file

```
Host tunnel
    HostName 192.168.224.143
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/mine.key
    LocalForward 18888 192.168.224.143:8888
    User username
```

and then running,

```
ssh -f -N tunnel
```

Is there a way to start this tunnel without running the ssh `ssh -f -N tunnel` command explicitly?

I would like to establish this tunnel whenever my machine boots up.  Do not want to add it in init script. Can it be done with SSH configuration itself?

Comment: Maybe with Puppet/Chef/Ansible kind of solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. SSH configuration is not designed to start something for you automatically. You need to add it to your startup applications or init script/systemd service, if you want to start it automatically after the network.

I also recommend you to use `autossh` which will take care of re-establishing the tunnel, if it fails for some reason.